# Unable to connect to chrome debugger from Device/Genymotion

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, react-native, genymotion

I am having the problem where I am not able to debug my application using chrome debugger. It is too sluggish and heavy to use android studio and use its terminal. Being a javascript styled application(Developing on React native), Android Studio debugging doesn't suit well.

I am able to see the device in chrome(advanced settings). But, when I click on "Debug in Chrome", I get the following error-
[image: Error]

Chrome connected Devices-

[image: Devices]

I am running the following commands in my terminal so that my device gets connected via reverse port forwarding-

```
react-native start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

I am running these 2 commands `react-native start` & `react-native run-android` so that the app will be installed on the phone & JS bundle loads on the device.

But, the following configurations have been made in Chrome port forwarding-

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Please let me know if the port that I am using in chrome wrong? What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Comment: Does anything get printed in the LogCat?

Comment: LogCat meaning, in Android Studio? Yes. I am currently using it to work. As I said, its not very developer-friendly especially when you are working with JS code.

Comment: @Blundell I added more information to the question.

Comment: I mean, do the logs say anything: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html

Comment: Yes "adb logcat" gives a lot of log statements running live to infinity.

Comment: i hope this will help you http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: @bozzmob you can use this shell command to see only React-related log messages: adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V

Comment: @John Yes. Thanks for the command. But, I want to debug using chrome. JS is best if we can debug using Firefox/Chrome. You know it as well :)

Comment: @OmarAbdan Tried it. But, too much of coupling with the code is needed for this. And debugging is little slow & phone gets laggy with this.

Comment: @bozzmob you cannot debug Java code in Chrome. Debugging in Chrome only is possible because RN shifts the JavaScript execution process to Chrome.

Comment: @John I very well know that. If you can please read the question properly, I am speaking about Javascript debugging all the time. Not sure what you are trying to tell here.