# How to store settings the user can't edit?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm looking for a way to store settings on a React Native app (both iOS and Android), so that the user can't just open a file editor and edit the settings (mostly referring to Android here).

It's ok if they view it, just not edit it.

I also don't want to send it via the API every time for certain reasons (in other words, I can't just hit a JSON endpoint to fetch the data fresh every time so that it doesn't need to be stored).

I've heard of using something like a 'key store' but I've heard it's not implemented on Android?

PS: Ultimate 'security' is not the goal, its so that I can store certain settings about their account without fetching it every time. If someone really wants to decompile the app or sniff out all kinds of things about it, thats fine, but it will thwart 99.999% of attempts which is all I care about.

Comment: Don't know what exactly you meant under 'key store' but probably it is variables in gradle settings - which is fixed according to build type - so it's not your case. Again I may misunderstood, but is shared preferences or database isn't suitable? You can also encrypt it's content if you want. But users with root devices will have access to any file anyway.

Comment: Well for instance I want to store their current plan, as well as whether some features are enabled. Are these things easily editable on android if I use AsyncStorage? I realize jailbreak iOS users could do that but I dont care because thats a small %

Comment: In fact, most users will not searching for files with settings. And it also seems that not even every developer can find such files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372057/where-is-asyncstorage-data-physically-located-on-android-devices

Comment: When you say 'root devices', is that by default what an android phone comes with, or is that similar to jailbreaking? I'm not very familiar with android. I suppose ultimately my question is... how easy is it to modify asyncstorage from android, on just your average user/consumer. Is it like iOS Jailbreaking where it requires some know-how?

Comment: Ah, intersting link...

Comment: Root devices is like jailbreak, you're right. And again I say, that it's rather difficult to find these files and especially edit.

Comment: there is persistent storage for react called AsyncStorage  -- https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html