# React Native AsyncStorage location and use

Tags: ios, mobile, react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to React Native and I am trying to grasp the use of AsyncStorage. I've reviewed the documentation and looked at a few wrappers available but cannot find the answers to a couple questions I have.

1. What would be the best way to add key-value pairs to AsyncStorage if I only need to add this data one time. It is not data that users would be adding aside from myself. For example, I want to add key-value pairs where the key is an item and the value is a description of that item. The description may be a couple paragraphs long. Do I need to build a component that handles the adding/updating/deleting of this data? This leads to my second question.
2. Is there a place I can view the data in AsyncStorage. I can't seem to find any information regarding the location of this data. Is there a file somewhere in the application or in xcode that I can view and/or directly update?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my suggestions to your questions:

> 1. What would be the best way to add key-value pairs to AsyncStorage...

AsyncStorage for ReactNative is intend to store unencrypted, simple key value pair data format. I would like to suggest if data size is more than don't go for AsyncStorage but use your web server to store your description and fetch it in your app. It's very handy when you want to change it. Keep in mind AsyncStorage is not secure because it's store data in unencrypted format and it's easily accessible if phone is rooted. If you still want to store data in AsyncStorage then encrypt it and then store.

> 2. Is there a place I can view the data in AsyncStorage...

you can follow my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43781842/3012993) answer.